# How do you calculate resistance needed for an inductive load?

Tags: resistors

If you have a 250W inductive load such as a DC motor, and you want to reduce the speed using a variable resistor (such as a Wirewound Ceramic Potentiometer Variable Rheostat Resistor), how do you calculate the maximum resistance needed? Do I use Ohm’s Law? If so, how? Also, how do you calculate the wattage needed? Would it be 250W, or something substantially lower? I read somewhere that the resistor would dissipate 1/3 of the power, but is that a universal rule? How do you calculate the power required too?

I tried eyeballing it with 6R and 12R, and both prevent the motor from working completely. I’ve used 3R on the motor, which doesn’t prevent it from working but doesn’t slow it down enough for my needs (so I’m imagining I need something between 3R and 6R).

It would be useful to know the required resistor values for both 12V and 6V power sources. Does voltage matter when calculating the required resistor?

**Edit:** I appreciate that introducing resistance is not the most efficient way of reducing a DC fan speed; the question is mostly academic as this is part of the potential solution. I’m also reducing the voltage and using PWM (but PWM makes the motor whine, so I’m experimenting with different approaches and combinations).

Comment: This is not how you do it. You use a lower voltage if you want a lower speed. You can use PWM control. As far as the motor is concerned the voltage is Vin * D where D is the duty cycle of the PWM control signal.

Comment: Nick, perhaps the best place to go when looking how to vary and reduce the speed of a DC motor is to examine the schematic for a good quality treadmill. Varying the speed under varying loads is pretty much ***what they do***. It's their primary business. Most treadmills probably use bigger DC motors than you are considering, but they will have all the basic elements you should study.

Comment: @mkeith I have edited my question.

Comment: @jonk Great idea, I’ll do some research.

Comment: If the motor is whining, use a PWM frequency that is too high for humans to hear. For example, 25 kHz is plenty high. Most people can't hear 20 kHz but a few mostly young people might be able to hear it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a series resistor to control the speed of a DC motor is a very old and inefficient method for controlling motor speed, but it is simple and a good starting point for studying motors. If the motor field is a permanent magnet or is a separately powered field winding, it is quite simple. In that case, you use the equivalent circuit shown below.

If you don't know the armature resistance, assume that the it is the supply voltage divided by the motor's locked-rotor (stall) current. Alternatively, assume that it is 10% of the supply voltage divided by the motor's full-load current or that it reduces the full-speed back emf, e(t) in the diagram to 90% of the supply voltage, Va(t).

If you have a 12-volt motor that produces 250 watts of mechanical power, assume e(t) is 10.8 volts at rated speed and load. The rated current is then 250/10.8 = 23.1 amps. If you want a to put a rheostat in series to reduce the speed to 1/3 of rated speed, You would need e(t) to be 10.8/3 = 3.6 volts. You need the voltage across the rheostat be e(t) 10.8 - 3.6 = 4.5 volts. The resistance must then be 4.5 V / 23.1 A = 0.19 ohms. The rheostat power will be the rheostat voltage multiplied by the rheostat current or 23.1 x 4.5 = 104 watts.

I have assumed that the torque required to turn the load is not reduced when the speed is reduced and therefore the current drawn by the motor is not reduced. If the load is a fan or centrifugal pump, reducing the speed reduces the required motor torque in proportion to the speed squared - 1/3 speed requires 1/9 torque and 1/9 current. In that case, the rheostat power at 1/3 speed is considerably less.

[image]

Note that in addition to wasting power, the added series resistance causes the motor's speed to change more when the load changes. Consequently, a series resistor that slows the motor down a little when the motor is not connected to a load will slow it down a lot when the the motor is fully loaded.

Note also that the inductance and the inertia of the motor and load are only relevant for calculations involving rapid voltage and speed changes. The load friction and the internal friction of the motor are lumped together for purposes other than calculating motor efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

The coil of a DC motors is not only an inductor, it also has some resistance due to copper losses. Make sure your model of the motor includes both inductance and the DC resistance of the coil. For the inductance, consider steady state condition. In DC the steady state condition of an inductor is simply a short. You can calculate the steady state current simply by using ohms law with the series combination of your coil DC resistance + your speed limiting resistor. Speed limiting resistor power is simply I^2 *R. For extra safety chose a resistor with a wattage of 2× (I^2 *R).

You will find that using a resistor to control the speed of a motor is not the best way. You are losing power to heat in the resistor and you can't actively control the speed while the motor is running. It is better to control it with a PWM square wave signal. You would vary the duty cycle to achieve different motor speeds. We typically use a circuit called an H-bridge to control both the speed and direction of a DC motor using a series of PWM signals.